# tableau Web Data Connector Loading Data forever

Tags: tableau-api

I have followed all the steps in the tutorial to install WDC.

Also, in the simulation my example works properly. 
However, when I try to load the data in tableau, the data "load" forever.

Any idea what might be?

Comment: Have you got any error in JavaScript console (for JS, Security or log)?

Comment: No, thats the strange thing. There is nothing that shows any error on the js.

Comment: I had the same problem and the reason for it was SOP, so that I have got an error in the security tab. So because you've got no error, I have no idea.